# Wizard accessing previously deleted SDK folder

Tags: java, android, linux, android-studio, sdk

I'm trying to set up my Android Studio environment on my Ubuntu through the Wizard but it doesn't go further than trying to download the 'android_m2repository_r47.zip' folder.

I had a previous session with Android Studio but deleted it meanwhile (and the SDK folder as well). Now I'm trying to install it again but the Wizard is trying to access the missing SDK folder to set it as the current SDK.

I've downloaded sdk-tools from 'https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html' but it's not the same SDK folder as I previously had and can't seem to find the SDK anywhere since every link directs me to the Android Studio download.